# Raspberry - Issue with cron automation

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi

I have an issue with cron job on a Raspberry Pi.
I've search the internet and StackOverflow but nothing seems to fix my problem.

I'm new to Linux and think I might have broken something that I don't understant yet.

So : Cron tasks work but not fully.
I have a test script called **test2.py** writing in a file and printing File created in the console.

When I run this script myself, it works.
When I run this script with cron, it prints the "File created" but won't create the file or write in it.

I watched syslog, cron is running the task and logging in a file. This log file only give me the print output and no other error. File was not created.

Where did I mess this up ?

TLDR : Cron run the task, I can see the script print but not writing in a file.

**test2.py :**

```
file = open('testfile.txt','w')
file.write('Hello World')
file.close()
print('File created')
```

**This is the Crontab entry :** */1 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /var/www/test2.py >> /tmp/cron.log 2>&1

**Here are the perm on the files :**
273281 4.0K -rw-r--r--  1 pi      pi        211 Dec 17 11:32 test2.py
Or, not working either :
273281 4.0K -rwxrwxrwx  1 pi      pi        211 Dec 17 11:32 test2.py

Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Try `open('/tmp/testfile.txt','w')` then you will see the file being generated at `/tmp/testfile.txt`. I don't know where the working directory of a cron job is. The file is generated somewhere.

Comment: THANK YOU ! :D
I've been working on this for some hours, questioned my perm, users and everything.
That was simply a path issue.

Solved for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Tin Nguyen solved this for me.
It was simply a path issue. File is created somewhere. My path was relative and cron directory is not the same as the one I ran the script from.

Thanks a lot.